# Select box issue. Options are wider than the box

Tags: jquery, css, forms

I have an issue where I am using a simple and popular way to hide the native select arrow of a select box by wrapping the select box in a div that is not as wide as the select box. A background image would normally then sit in the div as a replacement. Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/LUzKL/1/.

```
<div class="styled">
<select required="" name="" id="">
    <option value=""> Title </option>
    <option value="Mr"> Mr</option>
    <option value="Mr"> Mrs</option>
    <option value="Ms"> Ms </option>
</select>
</div
```

However when you select the box, the options are wider than the select box. I don't mind this, and probably most of the world doesn't care either. Unfortunately my client does. Apart from rewriting this in JS or using a plugin, is there a way of getting around it? It must also work in IE8.

Comment: This is an incredibly hacky way of styling a `select` element, and I wouldn't say it's very common. Use a javascript library to style it for you, such as Bootstrap or Select2.

Comment: In your CSS `select{width: 111%;}` ???

Comment: @A.Wolff i think he is trying to hide out the default arrow

Comment: @PrasanthKC ha ok, not really read the subject, my bad

Comment: You can decrease width to 200px & add ` -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;` in your css . It will hide the arrow http://jsfiddle.net/LUzKL/2/ ..I agree with Rory McCrossan

Comment: @Manish your fiddle works perfectly in chrome, but not in FF or IE

Comment: @PrasanthKC Dint test in other browsers thats y posted in comment ,just gave an option:)

Comment: I have come across a similar issue when using the same hack. My solution was to expand the entire select using jquery when the box is clicked on. I can post it as an answer if you like, but there was an issue with IE on windows XP.

Comment: Thanks guys. @TheWaxMann do you have example of this?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this with the code given in your fiddle. [Click this link to see working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/C98Ak/2/)

Unfortunately there was no background image in your fiddle, so I just added the first one I found on a google image search.

Here is the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('select:not(.short)')
    .bind('focus mouseover', function () {
        $(this).addClass('expand').removeClass('clicked'); 
     })
    .bind('click', function () { $(this).toggleClass('clicked'); })
    .bind('mouseout', function () { if (!$(this).hasClass('clicked')) { 
      $(this).removeClass('expand'); } 
     })
    .bind('blur', function () { $(this).removeClass('expand clicked'); });
});
```

and the additional css

```
select.expand {
    width: 200px !important;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: I have just noticed your comment about working in IE8. This does not work in any version of IE, sorry. IE ignores the appearance css property. I have updated the fiddle with an attempt at making it work in IE, but it is not ideal: [link to new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/C98Ak/5/)

Comment: Thanks, yeah, unfortunately IE doesn't like to play nicely. I don't think there is a clear-cut solution to this except a jquery plugin, which isn't an option with this client as approval process is a nightmare. They'll just have to accept it.

Comment: I understand, I have had similar clients. I have been playing about with this today and the closest thing I can get is IE10 compatibility. There may be hacks for other versions, but I do not know of them. [Here is the IE10 version](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/C98Ak/7/)